# Querying content of Data.Persist list

Tags: haskell, persistent

I can define a model like this:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Model
  intList [Int]
|]
```

Is there a way to run a `selectList` such that it would return a collection of models that contain a given value? For example, if I insert:

```
m1 <- insert $ Model [1,2,3]
m2 <- insert $ Model [3,4,5]
m3 <- insert $ Model [5,6,7]
```

I would like to run a query to return all records that contain `3` in their `intList`, that is `m1` and `m2`.

Comment: I suppose `intList` is going to be persisted in as SQL table, as a field of a record. If this is correct, this effectively breaks 1NF and SQL queries won't support it. I can imagine that objects are serialized for storage using `show`, so you'll end up with `[1, 2, 3]` which you could look up for individual elements as a string using `LIKE`, albeit inefficiently.

Comment: It's serialized as a varchar "[1,2,3]". Yes, `LIKE` comes to mind but it's rather inelegant if I need to drop down to raw SQL to perform a query on something defined in Haskell.

Comment: I'd rather add a 1:N table and made an extra join, operating in a well-understood 2NF/3NF relational world.